# Error: undefined function imap_open() when executing php file in remote server

Tags: php, imap

I am using remote server and I have implemented a email extractor in my server to read emails.The code works fine in my local computer but when I execute it in my server.I am having following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in /var/www/html/bpcmu/user/email_extractor.php:10
```

I have found a solution that my php has not allowed imap and need to install it on my remote server too. Here is my remote server details.

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.4 (Ootpa)"
VERSION_ID="8.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4 (Ootpa)"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.4"
```

Can someone explain how should I install it on my server? I tried with `yum -install php-imap` also. But didn't work that one too. Any other solution instead of installing that is also appreciated.

Update:
Error after trying installing php-imap

```
No match for argument: dnf-command(php-imap)
Error: Unable to find a match: dnf-command(php-imap)
```

Comment: When you say that you tried to install php-imap and it didn't work, what do you mean? The installation failed? What error did it fail with? Or it successfully installed but the error message still occurs?

Comment: @Ambulare, No match for argument: dnf-command(php-imap)
Error: Unable to find a match: dnf-command(php-imap)